Geometry Puzzle: Tangent Circles with Integer Radii
Take as a semi-related example a series of circles with radii 10, 9, 8, ..., 2, 1. Place the first (largest) circle in the center and subsequent circles around it, keeping tangency between subsequent circles and the central circle. It would look like this:

The puzzle prompt is this:
Find a sequence (any length, not necessarily 10) of strictly decreasing (strictly because otherwise you can pick seven 1s and pack a hex lattice) integer radii such that the final circle perfectly covers the central one. In other words, such that it is also tangent to the second circle (the first non-central). It might look like this:

I ended up posting this over at math SE as well.

This is totally fine as Puzzling, as similar mathematics-related puzzles have been accepted before. Do you have an answer or a set of answers in mind, or is this problem possibly unsolvable?

I have no idea if there is a solution.

A necessary condition for this to have a solution is the existence of a set of angles adding up to 2pi whose cosines are all rational.

answer for exactly 3 circles surrounding the central circle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket

Those are not decreasing in size.

When there are only 3 surrounding circles (with unique radii), they're always arranged in decreasing size.

But the central circle is not the largest.

This puzzle has already been solved using 30-digit numbers, but I'm interested in using smaller numbers.
I wrote some code to start with a central unit circle and the loop over values for the next-largest circle. Then I do a depth-first search, picking decreasing radii, and keeping track of the remaining angle and the least-common-multiple of denominators. The search is surprisingly narrow when the denominator is constrained and the tangent of all half-angles is required to be rational (update: or a rational multiplied by the root of some fixed integer). The search allows for an unlimited number of circles. The last radius in a valid configuration can be calculated instead of searched.
I found dozens of 6-digit solutions (see edit history for a few). But this 4-digit solution with fifteen circles is the best by far, and only barely avoids an overlap:

Zoomed view:

Other solutions
Here's 5-digit solution with central radius $42120$:


This last solution is incredible. Thanks for sharing!

edwardh's answer above gives eight circles with radii circa $10^{42}$:
rs = [
  1346015551088116451588241696826457667928305,
  1285983548348276483652942082564013466760320,
  1238768816482055499967626824541529444769070,
  1156239292571620556013720831252688362612000,
  990358148968489476126926154954692437512561,
  961539350943357825433592453776542736631070,
  908374343417739169873995450234402764477000,
  780821295607168322239085153945384792689735,
]

I coded up his approach in Python and threw a lot of laptop time at it. Today the computer finally found two smaller solutions, involving radii circa $10^{30}$:
rs = [
  3351747005653424648383741138532,
  3205723049598255148555654977125,
  2775693993058987197622141299968,
  2750071286250985696293256343360,
  2576265167388890063586881775735,
  2355770023351368908545664347968,
  2298393837394654407377433698465,
  2168159590729803674819757284343
]

# The corresponding t values are:
ts = [1/4, 16/67, 7/30, 2/9, 3/14, 39/187, 3/13]

and slightly smaller:
rs = [
  2941564115506288009572255050208,
  2641663701806844064724293810176,
  2588185711710249680183593951791,
  2354857694119310401212561211842,
  2236188368634576996067318957950,
  2089644243395382075169644129792,
  1996023217448211952755320125300,
  1967470772556389886966582369792
]
ts = [1/4, 7/29, 3/13, 2/9, 3/14, 29/138, 11/48]

They look like this:



r0 = 3351747005653424648383741138532
r0 = 2941564115506288009572255050208









I made the above images as SVG using this script. Sadly, StackExchange doesn't support rendering the SVG directly, so the images you see above are PNG screenshots.
I've blogged about this in "Tangent circles of integer radius" (2024-06-10), and updated the post to include Tom's much much smaller answers too (although I still don't know precisely how he's finding them).

That's a great improvement! You might be interested in also exploring solutions with 8 surrounding circles. IIRC, a new constraint is that the odd and even $\theta_i$ need to add to the same value, but then you can multiply/divide the even/odd $s_i$ values by an arbitrary constant.

@TomSirgedas: I'd certainly be interested to know if there's any relationship between the size/structure of the t fractions and the magnitude of the rs. There is certainly a smallest possible r0, and it would be cool to know how much we'd have to search to find it. (Very very naïvely: We know that there are only $2^{r_0}$ possible sets of decreasing-integer-radius circles for any given $r_0$. So there are only $\sum_{r_0=7}^{R-1}{2^{r_0}}\approx 2^{R}$ arrangements with $r_0 < R$, only some of which will be solutions. One of that finite number of solutions must be the smallest.)

I'm also really curious about adding more circles... There's a tension between using more bases for the LCM and the flexibility of the increased degrees of freedom.

I made a chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/153335/puzzling-tangent-circles

The closest I've got so far with some very brute force searching is this sequence of radii: 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14,  8,  5,  4,  3,  2. The final circle overlaps with the rightmost one by about 5.39x10e-6. I think I'll close this and post a similar question over in math.


Computer says (2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 17, 20, 23) is better: an overlap of only 7.09e-8 radians. And (1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 23, 26) is closer yet, with a gap of 1.48e-8. But I have no insights, just brute force and Python. :) If you do post on math.SE, please remember to post the link here!

Edited the question to include a link. Great finds!

Actually, both of my solutions (and maybe yours too) are already down in the noise of IEEE doubles, or very close to it, where the additions involved might not be associative, and the difference with 2pi might just be garbage. That said, here's my latest: (46, 36, 31, 30, 26, 21, 18, 15, 11, 10, 7, 6, 5). I'd be interested to hear from anyone who can do the computation more precisely than IEEE double. My program claims that the overlap there is 7.73426e-11 and that to close the loop perfectly the smallest circle's radius should be about 4.99999999866 instead of 5.

In Figure 12, one possible solution is depicted, with radii $1/146$, $1/27$, $1/23$, and $1/18$, respectively. This can easily be scaled by $90666$ times (the LCM) to become integers, namely $621$, $3358$, $3942$, $5037$. Judging from the magnitude of the numbers, its no wonder brute force computer search wasn't fruitful.

I think OP specifically wants the central circle to be the biggest whereas in this example it is the smallest.
